# Web deployment doesn't deploy index.cshtml

Tags: asp.net, razor, web-deployment

I have an ASP.NET website which has an `index.cshtml` file in the root. It's not tied to any controller or so, just a standalone Razor file. Whenever I deploy this project to an Azure Website, it doesn't deploy this file.

However it deploys a `portal.cshtml` in the same folder (root).

Is it because it expects `index.cshtml` files are disregarded if not in the `Views` folder? How could I make it deploy?

Comment: What is the Build Action of the file?

Comment: @haim770 right. Maybe its build action is Embedded Resource or something like that.

Comment: @haim770 That was it, thank you. It was set to `None`. I set it to `Content` and it works. So trivial yet I missed it. Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that the build action was set to `None`. I set it to `Content` and it was working. Credit goes to haim770's comment.

Comment: ok, it work. But what happen? I mean why it became "none" instead "content"?

Answer (score 1):

The build action is probably set to **None**. Set it to **Content**.